# Disabling a scanner after a certain amount of time

Tags: java, multithreading, timing

I am making a text based quiz and I want to make it so that if the player doesn't answer after a certain amount of time than it will act as if they got the question wrong. Im not really sure how to do this. I have a few ideas: Multithreading and Timers; However I have no idea how to do either.

Would either of those be good options for this?

Method with my question:

```
    public void questionOneA(String choice) {

    choice = scanner.nextLine();
    setWrong(false);

    switch(choice) {
    case "a":
        setLives(lives - 1);
        setWrong(true);

        if (getLives() > 0) {
            System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("WRONG!");
        }
        break;
    case "b":
        System.out.println("CORRECT!");
        setCorrect(true);
        break;
    case "c":
        setLives(lives - 1);
        setWrong(true);

        if (getLives() > 0) {
            System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("WRONG!");
        }
        break;
    case "d":
        setLives(lives - 1);
        setWrong(true);

        if (getLives() > 0) {
            System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("WRONG!");
        }
        break;
    case "skip":
        if (skips > 0) {
            setSkips(skips - 1);
            setCorrect(true);
        }

        else {
            System.err.println("You do not have any skips left!");
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.err.println("Please type an answer.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way you would for anything else that's based on doing something after a certain amount of time, with either a `Timer` or a `Delta-time loop` setting off an event (in this case one that corresponds to getting the question wrong) after a certain amount of (delta-)time.

Assuming your quiz runs in a loop (as games and game-like software should), then all you need to do is:

```
//Specify a maximum time and record it in a variable; in this case, I'm using milliseconds as unit, and 30 seconds of time.
long maxQuestionTime = 30000;

//Outside the game-loop, at start of a question, record a timestamp of the current time + max time.
long maxQuestionTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()+maxQuestionTime;

//Inside game-loop, check if current time has gone above the timestamp, effectively measuring elapsed time.
if(System.currentTimeMillis()>maxQuestionTimestamp){
    //fail the question here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Timer` class (`java.util.Timer`) is also multithreading. It does seem potentially suited for an application like this, although multithreading can introduce a substantial number of possible pitfalls. You could create a `Timer` and then schedule a `TimerTask` at the start of a question that will mark some flag to indicate the question is incorrect and disable accepting future answer attempts (or proceed to the next question or whatever action is appropriate) when the scheduled task occurs. This would necessitate creating a subclass of `TimerTask` that implements the abstract `run()` method to perform the action you want (marking the question incorrect, etc). You might even want to use the timer for other tasks (such as giving the user a moment to process the fact that they timed out on a question before moving on to the next).

The basic flow of using a `Timer` (as noted in the above example) is to create a subclass of `TimerTask` implementing `run()` to perform whatever task should occur at some time or at the end of some time duration (or repeatedly at some interval, which `Timer`s also support). Then instantiate a `Timer` and schedule an instance of this `TimerTask` subclass for execution at some time or after some interval (depending on which `schedule` method of `Timer` you call to schedule it). Then once that time is reached or interval has elapsed, the `run()` method you implemented will be called in the `Timer`'s background thread. For more specifics about `Timer` an

However, you'll need to watch out for pitfalls like race conditions (for example, if your task were to mark the question incorrect and then disable answers for it, if the user were to answer a question between your task marking it incorrect and disabling answering it you could get unexpected behavior). This is one of the common challenges of writing multithreaded code. If your overall program logic and flow is simple enough, careful design of what actions the task performs when and in what order might be sufficient to avert these issues, but you should use the utmost caution in dealing with updates from different threads to a shared piece of state (such as updating a boolean indicating the question was or wasn't correct from a timer task).

More general multithreading would certainly be usable, although `Timer` seems useful in that it is more specific to this particular sort of task.

As a (nonetheless very relevant) aside, I strongly caution against writing out a full method for each individual question, stylistically speaking, as it can lead to a large amount of duplicate or very similar code. Instead an approach like creating a class for questions (especially if all of your questions have a similar format) might be preferable, allowing you to (for example) create a new question by simply calling a constructor with question text and the index of the correct answer. Your question class might include a method that performs the answer checking in your example code that all the questions (as class instances) have without you needing to rewrite it for each one.